# What do these geth --rpcapi parameters mean: db and net?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, rpc

Many times in different guides I met the following string to start geth:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal"
```

[Here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) we can find commands provided by [admin](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#admin), [personal](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal), [eth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28703/full-list-of-geth-terminal-commands/28704#28704) options. But what do "db" and "net" mean and allow? And is "eth" option needed in case of web3j requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db` enables these functions:

```
db_putString
db_getString
db_putHex
db_getHex
```

`net` enables these functions:

```
net_version
net_peerCount
net_listening
```

As stated in: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Comment: The docs are now at https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API